# Tha xaml graphic disappear when it has more than one place in the page

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have add the xaml graphic code as below

```
<Viewbox x:key="Icon">
    <Canvas Name="Layer_1" Width="200" Height="200" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <Canvas.Resources/>
            <!--Unknown tag: metadata-->
            <!--Unknown tag: sodipodi:namedview-->
            <Canvas Name="g3">
                    <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path5" Fill="#000000">
                            <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M56.575 97l-9.064-21.467L37.18 51.066L26.847 75.209L17.765 97H11.99c2.322 7 12.895 14.08 25.602 14.08   S60.872 104 63.193 97H56.575z M27.767 75.602l9.407-21.973l9.415 22.292L55.491 97H18.848L27.767 75.602z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                            </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                    <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path7" Fill="#000000">
                            <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M181.87 97l-9.065-21.467l-10.332-24.467l-10.332 24.143L143.059 97h-5.773c2.321 7 12.894 14.08 25.602 14.08   c12.707 0 23.279-7.08 25.602-14.08H181.87z M153.061 75.602l9.406-21.973l9.416 22.292L180.786 97h-36.646L153.061 75.602z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                            </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                    <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path9" Fill="#000000">
                            <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry Figures="G169 42h-60.375c-0.968-3.1-3.476-5.511-6.625-6.363V14c0-1.381-1.119-2.5-2.5-2.5S97 12.619 97 14v21.638   c-3.148 0.853-5.656 3.264-6.625 6.362H30c-1.381 0-2.5 1.119-2.5 2.5S28.619 47 30 47h60.191c0.788 3.436 3.424 6.156 6.809 7.072   v102.682l-48 13.465V190h101v-19.781l-48-13.465V54.072c3.385-0.915 6.021-3.637 6.81-7.072J169c1.381 0 2.5-1.119 2.5-2.5   S170.381 42 169 42z G145 185H54v-10.992l45.5-12.762l45.5 12.762V185z M104.246 45.72c-0.016 0.085-0.027 0.173-0.048 0.257   c-0.046 0.199-0.11 0.391-0.18 0.58c-0.057 0.149-0.118 0.297-0.187 0.439c-0.408 0.842-1.048 1.541-1.844 2.023   c-0.285 0.173-0.594 0.311-0.913 0.425c-0.138 0.048-0.276 0.095-0.419 0.13c-0.106 0.027-0.213 0.051-0.321 0.07   c-0.272 0.048-0.548 0.084-0.834 0.084c-0.285 0-0.562-0.036-0.833-0.084c-0.109-0.02-0.217-0.043-0.323-0.07   c-0.142-0.035-0.278-0.082-0.415-0.129c-0.322-0.115-0.634-0.254-0.922-0.429c-0.792-0.481-1.429-1.179-1.836-2.017   c-0.07-0.145-0.132-0.293-0.189-0.443c-0.069-0.189-0.135-0.382-0.181-0.582c-0.02-0.083-0.03-0.168-0.046-0.253   c-0.047-0.268-0.083-0.539-0.083-0.82c0-0.3 0.036-0.592 0.089-0.877c0.025-0.137 0.066-0.269 0.104-0.399   c0.036-0.131 0.074-0.261 0.12-0.387c0.065-0.174 0.141-0.344 0.226-0.508c0.03-0.059 0.062-0.117 0.096-0.176   c0.109-0.191 0.226-0.379 0.358-0.555c0.367-0.484 0.819-0.895 1.34-1.211c0.289-0.176 0.602-0.315 0.925-0.431   c0.137-0.047 0.273-0.094 0.415-0.128c0.106-0.027 0.214-0.052 0.323-0.072c0.271-0.047 0.548-0.084 0.833-0.084   c0.286 0 0.562 0.037 0.834 0.084c0.108 0.021 0.216 0.044 0.321 0.071c0.143 0.035 0.281 0.082 0.419 0.13   c0.32 0.115 0.63 0.252 0.916 0.427c0.523 0.317 0.977 0.728 1.345 1.214c0.134 0.176 0.25 0.365 0.36 0.558   c0.031 0.057 0.063 0.112 0.093 0.171c0.086 0.165 0.161 0.336 0.227 0.512c0.047 0.125 0.084 0.254 0.119 0.383   c0.038 0.133 0.079 0.264 0.105 0.401c0.052 0.285 0.088 0.577 0.088 0.877C104.328 45.182 104.291 45.452 104.246 45.72y" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                            </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
            </Canvas>
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

it is a button that repeated use in one page. this code is in the application.resources. 
I use it with the staticresource.

```
    <Button Name="BarcodeButton" Content="{StaticResource Icon}"></Button>
```

When I clicked on Add button, it will add this new button to a page. The problem I have found is it display only latest button. The others was disappeared.

**edited**
I just found that I have to  x:Shared="False"

```
<Viewbox x:key="Icon" x:Shared="False" >
    <Canvas Name="Layer_1" Width="200" Height="200" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <Canvas.Resources/>
            <!--Unknown tag: metadata-->
            <!--Unknown tag: sodipodi:namedview-->
            <Canvas Name="g3">
                    <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path5" Fill="#000000">
                            <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M56.575 97l-9.064-21.467L37.18 51.066L26.847 75.209L17.765 97H11.99c2.322 7 12.895 14.08 25.602 14.08   S60.872 104 63.193 97H56.575z M27.767 75.602l9.407-21.973l9.415 22.292L55.491 97H18.848L27.767 75.602z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                            </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                    <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path7" Fill="#000000">
                            <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M181.87 97l-9.065-21.467l-10.332-24.467l-10.332 24.143L143.059 97h-5.773c2.321 7 12.894 14.08 25.602 14.08   c12.707 0 23.279-7.08 25.602-14.08H181.87z M153.061 75.602l9.406-21.973l9.416 22.292L180.786 97h-36.646L153.061 75.602z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                            </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                    <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path9" Fill="#000000">
                            <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry Figures="G169 42h-60.375c-0.968-3.1-3.476-5.511-6.625-6.363V14c0-1.381-1.119-2.5-2.5-2.5S97 12.619 97 14v21.638   c-3.148 0.853-5.656 3.264-6.625 6.362H30c-1.381 0-2.5 1.119-2.5 2.5S28.619 47 30 47h60.191c0.788 3.436 3.424 6.156 6.809 7.072   v102.682l-48 13.465V190h101v-19.781l-48-13.465V54.072c3.385-0.915 6.021-3.637 6.81-7.072J169c1.381 0 2.5-1.119 2.5-2.5   S170.381 42 169 42z G145 185H54v-10.992l45.5-12.762l45.5 12.762V185z M104.246 45.72c-0.016 0.085-0.027 0.173-0.048 0.257   c-0.046 0.199-0.11 0.391-0.18 0.58c-0.057 0.149-0.118 0.297-0.187 0.439c-0.408 0.842-1.048 1.541-1.844 2.023   c-0.285 0.173-0.594 0.311-0.913 0.425c-0.138 0.048-0.276 0.095-0.419 0.13c-0.106 0.027-0.213 0.051-0.321 0.07   c-0.272 0.048-0.548 0.084-0.834 0.084c-0.285 0-0.562-0.036-0.833-0.084c-0.109-0.02-0.217-0.043-0.323-0.07   c-0.142-0.035-0.278-0.082-0.415-0.129c-0.322-0.115-0.634-0.254-0.922-0.429c-0.792-0.481-1.429-1.179-1.836-2.017   c-0.07-0.145-0.132-0.293-0.189-0.443c-0.069-0.189-0.135-0.382-0.181-0.582c-0.02-0.083-0.03-0.168-0.046-0.253   c-0.047-0.268-0.083-0.539-0.083-0.82c0-0.3 0.036-0.592 0.089-0.877c0.025-0.137 0.066-0.269 0.104-0.399   c0.036-0.131 0.074-0.261 0.12-0.387c0.065-0.174 0.141-0.344 0.226-0.508c0.03-0.059 0.062-0.117 0.096-0.176   c0.109-0.191 0.226-0.379 0.358-0.555c0.367-0.484 0.819-0.895 1.34-1.211c0.289-0.176 0.602-0.315 0.925-0.431   c0.137-0.047 0.273-0.094 0.415-0.128c0.106-0.027 0.214-0.052 0.323-0.072c0.271-0.047 0.548-0.084 0.833-0.084   c0.286 0 0.562 0.037 0.834 0.084c0.108 0.021 0.216 0.044 0.321 0.071c0.143 0.035 0.281 0.082 0.419 0.13   c0.32 0.115 0.63 0.252 0.916 0.427c0.523 0.317 0.977 0.728 1.345 1.214c0.134 0.176 0.25 0.365 0.36 0.558   c0.031 0.057 0.063 0.112 0.093 0.171c0.086 0.165 0.161 0.336 0.227 0.512c0.047 0.125 0.084 0.254 0.119 0.383   c0.038 0.133 0.079 0.264 0.105 0.401c0.052 0.285 0.088 0.577 0.088 0.877C104.328 45.182 104.291 45.452 104.246 45.72y" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                            </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
            </Canvas>
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're setting the contents to a staticResource. you have to set the style or template to a staticResource.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="Icon">
    <Button>
        <Canvas>
            ...
        </Canvas>
    </Button>
</ControlTemplate>

<Button Name="BarcodeButton" Template="{StaticResource Icon}"></Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use style for button:

```
<Style x:Key="btnCustom" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Viewbox>
                        <Canvas Name="Layer_1" Width="200" Height="200" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
                            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                            <Canvas.Resources/>
                            <!--Unknown tag: metadata-->
                            <!--Unknown tag: sodipodi:namedview-->
                            <Canvas Name="g3">
                                <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path5" Fill="#000000">
                                    <Path.Data>
                                        <PathGeometry Figures="M56.575 97l-9.064-21.467L37.18 51.066L26.847 75.209L17.765 97H11.99c2.322 7 12.895 14.08 25.602 14.08   S60.872 104 63.193 97H56.575z M27.767 75.602l9.407-21.973l9.415 22.292L55.491 97H18.848L27.767 75.602z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                                    </Path.Data>
                                </Path>
                                <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path7" Fill="#000000">
                                    <Path.Data>
                                        <PathGeometry Figures="M181.87 97l-9.065-21.467l-10.332-24.467l-10.332 24.143L143.059 97h-5.773c2.321 7 12.894 14.08 25.602 14.08   c12.707 0 23.279-7.08 25.602-14.08H181.87z M153.061 75.602l9.406-21.973l9.416 22.292L180.786 97h-36.646L153.061 75.602z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                                    </Path.Data>
                                </Path>
                                <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path9" Fill="#000000">
                                    <Path.Data>
                                        <PathGeometry Figures="G169 42h-60.375c-0.968-3.1-3.476-5.511-6.625-6.363V14c0-1.381-1.119-2.5-2.5-2.5S97 12.619 97 14v21.638   c-3.148 0.853-5.656 3.264-6.625 6.362H30c-1.381 0-2.5 1.119-2.5 2.5S28.619 47 30 47h60.191c0.788 3.436 3.424 6.156 6.809 7.072   v102.682l-48 13.465V190h101v-19.781l-48-13.465V54.072c3.385-0.915 6.021-3.637 6.81-7.072J169c1.381 0 2.5-1.119 2.5-2.5   S170.381 42 169 42z G145 185H54v-10.992l45.5-12.762l45.5 12.762V185z M104.246 45.72c-0.016 0.085-0.027 0.173-0.048 0.257   c-0.046 0.199-0.11 0.391-0.18 0.58c-0.057 0.149-0.118 0.297-0.187 0.439c-0.408 0.842-1.048 1.541-1.844 2.023   c-0.285 0.173-0.594 0.311-0.913 0.425c-0.138 0.048-0.276 0.095-0.419 0.13c-0.106 0.027-0.213 0.051-0.321 0.07   c-0.272 0.048-0.548 0.084-0.834 0.084c-0.285 0-0.562-0.036-0.833-0.084c-0.109-0.02-0.217-0.043-0.323-0.07   c-0.142-0.035-0.278-0.082-0.415-0.129c-0.322-0.115-0.634-0.254-0.922-0.429c-0.792-0.481-1.429-1.179-1.836-2.017   c-0.07-0.145-0.132-0.293-0.189-0.443c-0.069-0.189-0.135-0.382-0.181-0.582c-0.02-0.083-0.03-0.168-0.046-0.253   c-0.047-0.268-0.083-0.539-0.083-0.82c0-0.3 0.036-0.592 0.089-0.877c0.025-0.137 0.066-0.269 0.104-0.399   c0.036-0.131 0.074-0.261 0.12-0.387c0.065-0.174 0.141-0.344 0.226-0.508c0.03-0.059 0.062-0.117 0.096-0.176   c0.109-0.191 0.226-0.379 0.358-0.555c0.367-0.484 0.819-0.895 1.34-1.211c0.289-0.176 0.602-0.315 0.925-0.431   c0.137-0.047 0.273-0.094 0.415-0.128c0.106-0.027 0.214-0.052 0.323-0.072c0.271-0.047 0.548-0.084 0.833-0.084   c0.286 0 0.562 0.037 0.834 0.084c0.108 0.021 0.216 0.044 0.321 0.071c0.143 0.035 0.281 0.082 0.419 0.13   c0.32 0.115 0.63 0.252 0.916 0.427c0.523 0.317 0.977 0.728 1.345 1.214c0.134 0.176 0.25 0.365 0.36 0.558   c0.031 0.057 0.063 0.112 0.093 0.171c0.086 0.165 0.161 0.336 0.227 0.512c0.047 0.125 0.084 0.254 0.119 0.383   c0.038 0.133 0.079 0.264 0.105 0.401c0.052 0.285 0.088 0.577 0.088 0.877C104.328 45.182 104.291 45.452 104.246 45.72y" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                                    </Path.Data>
                                </Path>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Canvas>
                    </Viewbox>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Use style for your button:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource btnCustom}"/>
```

With this style I have button like this:
[image]

I hope this is sample will help you)))